# @id breaks Google Rich Results Logo detection

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

Why does an [`@id` node identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#node-identifiers) referencing the top node stop [Google's Rich Results test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) detecting a logo?

For example it says "Page not eligible for rich results known by this test" for the following, but if you remove the `"about"` property then it successfully detects the logo:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@id": "https://acme.com/",
    "@type": "Corporation",
    "url": "https://acme.com/",
    "mainEntityOfPage": "https://acme.com/",
    "name": "Acme",
    "image": "https://acme.com/logo.png",
    "logo": "https://acme.com/logo.png",
    "brand": {
        "@id": "https://acme.com/#brand",
        "@type": "Brand",
        "logo": "https://acme.com/logo.png",
        "name": "Acme",
        "url": "https://acme.com/"
    },
    "subjectOf": {
        "@id": "https://acme.com/about",
        "@type": "AboutPage",
        "mainEntityOfPage": "https://acme.com/about",
        "name": "About Acme",
        "url": "https://acme.com/about",
        "about": {
            "@id": "https://acme.com/"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? Is there a way to work around it besides removing all `@id` references to the top node? In our real JSON-LD I also use `"author": {"@id": "https://acme.com/"}` for various offered `SoftwareApplication`s, which I'd rather not remove.